# TabView button doesn't work when initialized to 2nd tab

Tags: swiftui, tabview

I have a scrollable tabview that displays on the click of either button in the home view (ContentView). I want the 1st tab to show when "View 1" is clicked, and the 2nd tab to show when "View 2" is clicked. Once the tabview is opened, it should still function properly, meaning the tab buttons and scrolling still works correctly. Now that I think about it, this is similar to clicking on the "Followers" or "Following" button on Instagram.

When I click on "View 2" it shows the 2nd tab correctly, but when I click on the tab button for View 1, the screen does not show the View 1 text. [Video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM3ky.gif). Does anyone know how to fix this bug? Thanks!

ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            HStack {
                NavigationLink {
                    ScrollTab(currentTab: 0)
                } label: {
                    Text("View 1")
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .fontWeight(.semibold)
                }
                
                NavigationLink {
                    ScrollTab(currentTab: 1)
                } label: {
                    VStack {
                        Text("View 2")
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    }
                    .frame(width: 76)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

ScrollTab.swift:

```
struct ScrollTab: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Int = 0
    
    init(currentTab: Int) {
        _currentTab = State(initialValue: currentTab)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
            
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                Text("This is view 1").tag(0)
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.currentTab = 0
                    }
                Text("This is view 2").tag(1)
                    .onAppear() {
                        self.currentTab = 1
                    }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .background(Color.secondary)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct TabBarView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    @Namespace var namespace
    
    var tabBarOptions: [String] = ["View 1", "View 2"]
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 20) {
            ForEach(Array(zip(self.tabBarOptions.indices,
                              self.tabBarOptions)),
                    id: \.0,
                    content: {
                index, name in
                TabBarItem(currentTab: self.$currentTab,
                           namespace: namespace.self,
                           tabBarItemName: name,
                           tab: index)
                
            })
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .background(Color.orange) // <<<< Remove
        .frame(height: 80)
    }
}

struct TabBarItem: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    let namespace: Namespace.ID
    
    var tabBarItemName: String
    var tab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            self.currentTab = tab
        } label: {
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(tabBarItemName)
                if currentTab == tab {
                    Color.black
                        .frame(height: 2)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: "underline",
                                               in: namespace,
                                               properties: .frame)
                } else {
                    Color.clear.frame(height: 2)
                }
            }
            .animation(.spring(), value: self.currentTab)
        }
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your expected result is, but are you saying that you want the forwarding view to first show View1 when you click on View1 at Home and to first show View2 when you click on View2 at Home?  If that's the case, I can fix it easily.  But I'm going grocery shopping in several minutes and won't be back for 2 hours.

Comment: No, that part is working fine. In the video, notice how when I click the "View 1" tab button first, the page doesn't scroll to the "This is View 1" text. It remains as "This is View 2" text. That's the issue I want to resolve.

Comment: I see what you mean.  You have a problem with the ScrollTab view.  Under the line of TabView(selection: self.$currentTab), you have two Text views with `onAppear`.  That's where a problem occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated with the comment above, under the line of TabView(selection: self.$currentTab), you have two Text views with onAppear. That's where a problem occurs.

So I have separated those two views from the ScrollTab view and created another named TextView as follows.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollTab: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Int = 0
    
    init(currentTab: Int) {
        _currentTab = State(initialValue: currentTab)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
            
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                TextView(currentTab: $currentTab)
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .background(Color.secondary)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

#Preview {
    ScrollTab(currentTab: 1)
}

struct TextView: View {
    @Binding var currentTab: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if currentTab == 0 {
                Text("This is view 1")
            } else {
                Text("This is view 2")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't touched ContentView and other actors.

**UPDATE**

I have gotten rid of TextView.  You can now scroll it horizontally to switch tabs.

```
struct ScrollTab: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Int = 0
    
    init(currentTab: Int) {
        _currentTab = State(initialValue: currentTab)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
            
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                ForEach(0...1, id: \.self) { number in
                    VStack {
                        if number == 0 {
                            Text("This is view 1")
                        } else {
                            Text("This is view 2")
                        }
                    }.tag(number)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .background(Color.secondary)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
struct ScrollTab: View {
    @State private var currentTab: Int = 0
    
    init(currentTab: Int) {
        _currentTab = State(initialValue: currentTab)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Spacer()
        VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 0) {
            TabBarView(currentTab: self.$currentTab)
            
            TabView(selection: self.$currentTab) {
                VStack {
                    if currentTab == 0 {
                        Text("This is view 1").tag(0)
                    } else {
                        Text("This is view 2").tag(1)
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
            .background(Color.secondary)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this does fix that issue. However, the ScrollTab view is no longer scrollable. When I try to swipe on the screen, it doesn't move. I'm going to look into this issue separately, but if you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: I've fixed it, I suppose.  Please take a look.

Comment: Thank you. The scrolling does work now. However, the original problem where clicking the View 1 button from the View 2 screen doesn't update the screen is back lol. Such a weird issue.

Comment: Oops...  I thought it was working.  I'll take a look.  I'm sorry about that.

Comment: I've posted the 2nd updated version.  This time, I've posted a GIF animation to show that it's working.  Let me know whether or not it's work for you this time.  Ughghg...